# Expression in SSIS returning date that does not exist

Tags: date, ssis, expression

I have an expression that returns the date 6 months ago in the format 03/31/2021. This has been functioning as desired until today when it returned the date 09/31/2020, which does not exist. How can write the expression to get the desired results?

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH( DATEADD( "MONTH" , -6,GETDATE())), 2) + 
"/"+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()), 2) + 
"/" +(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD( "MONTH" , -6,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the second set of string logic

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()), 2)
```

It is getting the day number of current day (31). You likely intended to back that off 6 months as you do with Year and Month.

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(DATEADD("MONTH" , -6,GETDATE()), 2)
```

Were it me, I would create a new variable, `AnchorDate` and set Evaluate as Expression to True and use the expression

```
DATEADD("MONTH", -6, GETDATE())
```

I can test that, yes it's 6 months ago.

Now my date string becomes cleaner as I am not repeating (or not in 1/3 of your case) the date manipulation logic.

```
      RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(@[User::AnchorDate]), 2) + 
"/" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY  (@[User::AnchorDate]), 2) + 
"/" +(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(@[User::AnchorDate])
```